# Mongodb - Update an attribute in array from another attribute in the same array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm have the following collection in MongoDB:

```
{
  "_id":"123456",
  "history":[
     {
        "date": 1674926893449,
        "name": "Hello"
     },
     {
        "date": 1631548766655,
        "name": "Super"
     }
  ]
}
```

The attribute `history.date` is currently the unix timestamp but I'm restructuring the object and want to have an attribute of type `Date` using the Mongo operator `$toDate`. I need to make a query which would take the `date` attribute and create an attribute `dateTime` in the same array element, something like:

```
{
  "_id":"123456",
  "history":[
     {
        "date": 1674926893449,
        "name": "Hello",
        "dateTime": 2023-01-28T17:28:13.449+00:00
     },
     {
        "date": 1631548766655,
        "name": "Super",
        "dateTime": 2021-09-13T15:59:26.655+00:00
     }
  ]
}
```

The `date` attribute might be 0 so in that case, the attribute `dateTime` should have `null` value.

I ended up with this query but I miss something:

```
db.invoice.updateMany({"history.dateTime":{$exists:false}}, {$set : { "history.$[elem].dateTime" : { $cond: { if: { $gt: [ "history.$[elem].$date", 0 ] }, then: { $toDate: "history.$[elem].$date" }, else: null }}}}, { "arrayFilters": [{ "elem.dateTime": {$exists:false} }] })
```

In that case Mongo returns the error:

```
The dollar ($) prefixed field '$cond' in 'history.0.dateTime.$cond' is not valid for storage.
```

Any idea how can make I this works?
Thanks

Comment: You're mixing syntaxes here. Array filters can't be used with aggregation pipeline updates which $cond would be part of. I'd say you should try wrapping the second argument in square brackets (indicating agg pipeline syntax), drop the arrayFilters part, and see if you can get the right logic in place. You can use mongoplayground and $addFields to test the logic

Answer (score 0):

We can use the aggregation pipeline state: [`$addFields`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/). We use the `$match` stage and `$elemMatch` to filter the documents in which `history.dateTime` does not exist. The document with `_id: 2` will be filtered.

At the `$addFields` stage, we use `$map` to apply an expression to each item in an array and return an array with the applied results.

If the `history.date` is great than the `0` and `history.dateTime` field does not exists, create a `dateTime` field whose value is converted value of `history.date` by [`$toDate`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/), then use [`$mergeObjects`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) to combine current history(`$$h`) with the `{ dateTime: <ISO Date> }` object.

Else, return the current history(the one with `name: 'c'`) without any operations.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      history: {
        $elemMatch: {
          dateTime: {
            $exists: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "history": {
        $map: {
          input: "$history",
          as: "h",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $gt: [
                      "$$h.date",
                      0
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      {
                        $ifNull: [
                          "$$h.dateTime",
                          true
                        ]
                      },
                      true
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$h",
                  {
                    "dateTime": {
                      $toDate: "$$h.date"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              else: "$$h"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Input:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "history": [
      {
        "date": 1674926893449,
        "name": "Hello"
      },
      {
        "date": 1631548766655,
        "name": "Super"
      },
      {
        "date": 1631548766655,
        "name": "c",
        "dateTime": "2022-01-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "history": [
      {
        "date": 1674926893449,
        "name": "a",
        "dateTime": null
      },
      {
        "date": 1631548766655,
        "name": "b",
        "dateTime": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "history": [
      {
        "date": 1.674926893449e+12,
        "dateTime": ISODate("2023-01-28T17:28:13.449Z"),
        "name": "Hello"
      },
      {
        "date": 1.631548766655e+12,
        "dateTime": ISODate("2021-09-13T15:59:26.655Z"),
        "name": "Super"
      },
      {
        "date": 1.631548766655e+12,
        "dateTime": "2022-01-01",
        "name": "c"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qDi4cpbu9CG)